# In the following code I am not being able to enter value for variable 'b'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a;                    
    char b;                
    printf("A is ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("B is ");
    scanf("%c",&b);           
}
```

Comment: Either initialize `a` and `b`, or check return Value of `scanf`, because if `scanf` fails now, the variables may be left un-initialized (which is generally bad).

Comment: You joined this community today so welcome and take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :).

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that when you enter first character then after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a newline character (`\n`) is also passed to the input buffer along with that character. Since `scanf("%c",&a);` reads a single character at a time, it left behind `\n` in the  buffer for next call of `scanf`. This `\n` is read by your second `scanf` call.
Put a space before `%c` in `scanf` to consume that newline character.

```
scanf(" %c",&a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the scanf like this

```
 scanf(" %c", &b);
```

when you are after giving the value for first variable, you will give enter. Here `%c` will take that as input. So avoid this, make the whitespace before the control string. It will skip the whitespace character(newline, tab, space). And ask the input from the user.

You can verify that new line is taken as a input for second variable like this,

```
 printf("%d", b); // You will get the ascii value of new line.
```

when you  give the enter newline placed in the input buffer, then that value will taken by the scanf. So need of scanf ( getting the input) is done. so it doesn't ask the input from you.

Comment: Aren't you going to explain this?

Comment: Thanks. Why to do like this.?